# split a string in excel with no separator

Tags: worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2016

Superusers I am trying to create a formula in Excel 2016 to split a string into a column. I have tried the "test to columns", but my problem is that it does not accept a null separator.

What I am trying to do is to split into column a string with no separators, e.g:
'atta' to 'a', 't', 't', 'a', each character on a different cell. The string has no fixed length. I have also tried the 'replace' function, which may potentially do the job,  but I am not able to feed multiple value to the "start_num" argument (i.e. I could give it  1:len(my_string"), but I do not know how to do it). I would appreciate any help or suggestion. Please let me know if the question is not clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put this in the upper left corner of the results area:

```
=MID($A1,COLUMN(A:A),1)
```

Copy over sufficient to get the longest string and down the length of the data.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! That is a great solution! May I ask you to break it down to me, please? I checked the individual functions, but I am not sure why you added the "IFERROR"

Comment: The IFERROR is not needed, I made a assumption that was incorrect.  But the column(A:A) changes as the the formula is dragged/copied across, thus changing the start number of the mid from 1 to 2 to 3 to... @madmaxthc

Comment: That does the job, you're right. With or without the "IFERROR", the result is correct. Thanks again for responding so quickly!